# Consume third party API with Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have an third party API (api.foo.com), protected with Authentication and Authorizations. I can not edit server settings.

I would to create a Blazor WebAssembly (.NET 5) application and consume this REST API.

In my program class,

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        // builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient<FooClient>(c => c.BaseAddress = "https://api.foo.com/v1/");
    }
}
```

My `FooClient`:

```
public class FooClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    public FooClient(HttpClient httpClient) => _httpClient = httpClient;
    public Task<Foo> GetFoo(int id) => _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Foo>("foo/" + id);
    // ... other as GetAll(), Edit(Foo), ...
}
```

When I try, my browser's console shows:

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://api.foo.com/api/Authentification'
> from origin 'https://localhost:5001' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I've tried to add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors` NuGet package and implement an equivalent of `Startup` class.. I've not found where can I register the `Startup` class.

I've tried to add CORS headers in my `FooClient` as:

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
```

I've tried to add a HttpMessangeHandler to my FooClient, in `Program.Main`:

```
builder.Services
    .AddHttpClient<AltevaClient>(c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.foo.com/v1/"))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

...and implement my own version:

```
public class FooApiAuthorizationMessageHandler : AuthorizationMessageHandler
{
    public AltevaApiAuthorizationMessageHandler(
        IAccessTokenProvider provider, 
        NavigationManager navigationManager)
        : base(provider, navigationManager)
    {
        ConfigureHandler(
            authorizedUrls: new[] { "https://api.foo.com/v1/" },
            scopes: new[] { "example.read", "example.write" });
    }
}
```

In the two last cases, my browser's console shows:

> crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler' has been registered.

Ok! above `AddHttpClient`, I'd tried to add `BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler` in Services.

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

Browser's console shows:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler'.

And I cannot register `IAccessTokenProvider` as a Service.

> Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider' for service type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider'.

...And I don't found a "default" implementation...

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65858468/access-to-fetch-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-blazor-client-web-assembly

Comment: I've tried too, but I have the same console message: `Access to fetch at 'https://webapplication120210430131456.azurewebsites.net/api/Values' from origin 'https://localhost:5001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.` For the demo, I've published an API at https://webapplication120210430131456.azurewebsites.net/api/Values

Comment: Did you configure your Web Api to support CORS ?